# Create a new table from multiple tables with identical column names without declaring the column names

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that I'd like to pull data from and use the result set to create a new table. Note that each of these tables have identical column names.

```
CREATE TABLE smsout_32020Nov2014
     AS 
(SELECT    *
FROM smsout17nov2014b,smsoutnov32014,smsout

WHERE smsoutnov32014.shortcode = 32020

AND  smsout.shortcode = 32020

AND smsout17nov2014b.shortcode = 32020);
```

Problem  is that I am getting an error that there are duplicate column names

Is there a work around?

Comment: Your statement does not (try to) create a new table with the same structure as the others.  You are performing joins, so the result has all the columns from *each* of the joined tables.  That's where the duplicate column names are coming from.  What are you trying to achieve via those joins?

Comment: The joins help populate a resultset I want from these tables. Note that all these tables have the same column structure.

Comment: The joins **do not** help populate a result set you want.  They unquestionably give you a result set with a form different from what you want.  I cannot tell from the code what results you are hoping the joins will provide, therefore I am asking you.

Comment: Writing a join via the comma (`,`) operator instead of the `JOIN` operator does not make it any less a join.

Comment: The results are okay from the select statement and that is not the problem. The issue comes in where I try to create a new table from this resultset

Comment: It is still unclear what results you want, but the answer I already wrote makes a guess.  If you want something different then explain it *in words*.

Comment: The results from the `SELECT` statement are **NOT** ok if they are supposed to have the same form as each of the three base tables (as the question specifies).

Comment: I've rephrased the question maybe now we can be on the same page.

Comment: I have updated my answer to respond to what you now seem to be asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comments on your question, it is unclear what results you are actually trying to obtain.  Supposing that the question reflects a complete misunderstanding of join operations, however, it may be that `UNION ALL` is what you're actually looking for.  In particular, if you want all the rows of the three named tables for which the `shortcode` column has the value `32020`, then that would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE smsout_32020Nov2014 AS (
  SELECT smsout17nov2014b.*
  WHERE shortcode = 32030

  UNION ALL

  SELECT smsoutnov32014.*
  WHERE shortcode = 32030

  UNION ALL

  SELECT smsout.*
  WHERE shortcode = 32030
)
```

On the other hand, if the results you are selecting are in fact in the form you want, as you have revised your question to say, then you have no alternative but to assign explicit column names to ensure column name uniqueness (so at least for every column in two of the three base tables).  You can do this via aliases in the `SELECT` statement or via a column list in the outer `CREATE TABLE` statement (or both).  Your original question seemed to say that the workaround you wanted was a way to avoid doing that, but now it just seems to say that you want to fix the error.

It will be a bit simpler to do the patch up in the `SELECT` statement.  Based on your revised starting query, that would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE smsout_32020Nov2014 AS (
  SELECT
    smsout.*,
    m.col1 AS month_col1, m.col2 AS month_col2, ... m.shortcode AS month_shortcode,
    c.col1 AS code_col1,  c.col2 AS code_col2, ...  c.shortcode AS code_shortcode,
  FROM
    smsout17nov2014b m,
    smsoutnov32014 c,
    smsout
  WHERE smsoutnov32014.shortcode = 32020
    AND smsout.shortcode = 32020
    AND smsout17nov2014b.shortcode = 32020
);
```

The columns of your new table will be `col1`, `col2`, ... `shortcode`, `month_col1`, `month_col2`, ... `month_shortcode`, `code_col1`, `code_col2`, ... `code_shortcode`.

Note, by the way, that even if those results are in the *form* you want (which I find surprising), I have trouble believing that the rows are what you want.

Comment: Looks like you've been right all along. UNION ALL is what I require. The JOIN populates a wrong result set with multiple column duplicates.